# SQL seems to be saying that 1 is not an integer

Tags: sql, database, csv, import, integer

I am getting this error when trying to import and csv file into SQL:

> SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "1" 
>   Where: COPY nhl_rookies2, line 1, column player_rank: "1"

I am using DBeaver as my GUI (I am open to suggestions for a better free GUI for mac os).

I tried changing the data type to numeric but that threw a similar error.

```
create table nhl_rookies (
    player_rank integer,
    player varchar(32),
    goals integer,
    team char(3),
    league char(32),
    posistion varchar(2),
    season text,
    age integer,
    games_played integer,
    assists integer,
    points integer,
    rating integer,
    pim integer,
    even_strength_points integer,
    power_play_points integer,
    short_handed_points integer,
    game_winning_goals integer,
    shots_on_goal integer,
    shooting_perc numeric(3,1),
    ice_time integer,
    goals_per_game numeric(3,2),
    assists_per_game numeric(3,2),
    points_per_game numeric(3,2),
    shots_per_game numeric(3,2)
);

copy nhl_rookies2
from '/Users/aidanbarr/Downloads/NHL_rookies_20102018.csv'
delimiter ',';
```

I was expecting SQL to fill in the columns with the csv data.

here are the first few lines of my data:

1,10/4/18,1,19-029,NYR,,NSH,L,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,,15,12:41,0,0,2,6,25
2,10/6/18,2,19-031,NYR,@,BUF,L,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,18,17:18,0,1,1,6,14.3

Comment: which dbms are you using ?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: Ferst few lines of the CSV file you are loading would also be helpful here. Chances are that number "1" is quoted there.

Comment: I added the first few lines of my data to the original post.